# Items in array returning last one only

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am using this function to pass every element in an array to use it in an if statement The problem is that the function is always returning the last value of the array Please help.

```
function getQtyCheck()
{
    var qty;
    var id;
    var checkQty = new Array()
     if(localStorage.getItem("checkout")!=null || localStorage.getItem("checkout")!=""){
       checkQty = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkout"));
       for(var t =0; checkQty.length >t; t++){
         id = checkQty[t]; 
         t++;
         qty = checkQty[t];

       }//end for loop
      return {ids:id,qtys:qty}
     }//end checkout

}
```

Then in another part of the script I ma using these variables like this

```
var result = getQtyCheck();
    var id = result.ids;
    var qty = result.qtys;
    if(this.id == id){
var tqty = this.quantity-qty;
```

Comment: Which item would you like returned? Currently when your loop iterates for the last time, `id` and `qty` will contain values of the last element in the array.

Comment: I would like to retrun every item in the array

Comment: Not understanding how to do it can you please edit my code]

Comment: var result = getQtyCheck(); var id = result.ids; is not workin to retrieve the id and qty

Answer (score 3):

I think I'm following what you are trying to do now. You want to return every element in the array as an array of objects right?

```
function getQtyCheck() {
    var qty,
        id,
        checkQty = [],
        returnValues = [];
     if(localStorage.getItem("checkout")!=null && localStorage.getItem("checkout")!=""){
         checkQty = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkout"));
         for(var t =0, len = checkQty.length; len > t; t++){
             id = checkQty[t]; 
             t++;
             qty = checkQty[t];
             returnValues.push({ id: id, qty: qty });
         }
         return returnValues;
     }

}
```

In the loop, build  an array of the objects you want to return. After the loop, return the newly created array.

Comment: Was writing something like this, not as good though, as my answer. +1 for this :)

Comment: I would like to retrun every id and qty not as an array as individual variables

Answer (score 2):

Each loop iteration, you assign `id` and `qty` to the currently iterated item. Once the loop is over, you return an object with the LAST iterated item set to your variables. Since your `return` is immediately after the loop and using variables set within the loop, you will always get the last values.

Answer (score 1):

It's returning the last one every time because you're looping it which is adding it up, but then you're using `return` outside the loop, which is just going to get the last one that it ran.

You shouldn't `return` inside the for loop because it will try to return multiple times. What you can do though is `push` it to an `array` and then get it at the end.

Comment: Still does not work if i put the variable declare id the for lopp and return after inside the lopp

Comment: You shouldn't `return` inside the for loop because it will try to return multiple times. What you can do though is `push` it to an `array` and then get it at the end. @MichaelSultana

Comment: Not understanding how to do it can you please show me?

Comment: Please take a look at war10ck's answer